# Verification initialization failed: Sinch backend request failed with code: 40003 message: Invalid number

Tags: sms, verification, sinch

first. i live in south korea.

downloaded sinch verification example

and modify application_key

and launch...

but

i found this error code.

Verification initialization failed: Sinch backend request failed with code: 40003 message: Invalid number.

plz help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number needs to be entered in international format +countrycode+number